# Monitor for programming/reading - 4K IPS 60hz vs 4K VA 144hz?

Tags: monitors

I am working as a developer. I work per day 12-14hours, and I want to take care of my eye.

I am currently using Monitor Dell UltraSharp 43 4K, but I think this screen is too much for me, and I want to look at a too-large screen too close (2.5 feet). I also wear special glasses with blue-light filter and use blue-light filter monitor option.

I read many review about monitors, and I think based on two options:

- Gigabyte M32UC - Size 32" Pixel Type VA Max Refresh Rate 160 Hz Variable Refresh Rate Yes Native Resolution 3840 x 2160 HDR10 Yes
- Dell S2722QC - Size 27" Pixel Type IPS Max Refresh Rate 60 Hz Variable Refresh Rate Yes Native Resolution 3840 x 2160 HDR10 Yes

I bought these two monitor, and want one to return, one to leave.

At the moment better for me is Gigabyte, but I readed that IPS for coding is better, right?

VA is most harmful for long-working?

My main goals for new monitor:

- cleary text - 4K in my 43 Dell is very averge
- good for eyes

Comment: I don't think VA or IPS makes a difference for your health at all. They're just different ways of electronically controlling how much light goes through a layer in the screen. The backlight itself (brightness, flicker, etc.) is more relevant for eye health. IPS not not "better" for code in any objective way, people like text better on different screens for subjective reasons but they all can display text well enough to code on.

Comment: High refresh rate is also not that useful for coding/reading (ereaders generally have a refresh rate of 2hz or less)